# Calculate $\mathbb{E} W_{\tau + 1}$, $\mathbb{E}W^{2}_{\tau+1}$ and $\mathbb{E}W_{\tau \land 5}$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $W$ be a standard Wiener process. Let $\tau = \inf \{t \geqslant 0 : W_{t} = 4\}$.

Calculate:

a) $\mathbb{E} W_{\tau + 1}$

b) $\mathbb{E}W^{2}_{\tau+1}$

c) $\mathbb{E}W_{\tau \land 5}$

I guess that a) should be just $\mathbb{E} (W_{\tau + 1} - W_{\tau} + W_{\tau})$ = $\mathbb{E} W_1 + \mathbb{E}W_\tau = \mathbb{E}W_\tau$ , so I have to calculate $ \mathbb{E}W_\tau$. Although I'm not sure how - probably it won't be just an expected value of four increments?

Comment: Note that $W_{\tau}=4$ almost surely by the very definition of the stopping time and the continuity of the sample paths of Brownian motion.

Comment: So is it just $ \mathbb{E} W_{\tau} = P(W_{\tau} = 4) * 4 = 4$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So let's continue this :D
b) I'm trying to do it similarly: $\mathbb{E} W^{2}_{\tau +1} = 16 * \mathbb{P}(W_{\tau+1} = 4) = 16$ ?

Comment: No. We have $\mathbb{P}(W_{\tau}=4)=1$ but not $\mathbb{P}(W_{\tau+1}=4)=1$. Take your time to do the calculations properly. Start as in a): $$W_{\tau+1} = (W_{\tau+1}-W_{\tau}) + W_{\tau}$$ Square both sides, take expectations and see what you get.

Comment: You are right, I was trying to do it too fast.
Using your hint I get:
$\mathbb{E} W_{\tau +1}^{2} = \mathbb{E}( (W_{\tau+1} - W_{\tau} + W_{\tau})^2)) = \mathbb{E} (W_{\tau + 1} - W_{\tau})^2 + 2 \cdot \mathbb{E}(W_{\tau +1} - W_{\tau}) \cdot \mathbb{E} W_{\tau} + \mathbb{E} W_{\tau}^{2} = 1 + 1 \cdot 4^{2} = 17$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, looks good.

Comment: Do you know the strong Markov property?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Just want to add more details on calculating $E(W_{\tau + 1} - W_\tau)$ and $E[(W_{\tau + 1} - W_\tau)^2]$.

By iterative expectation law:
\begin{align}
  & E(W_{\tau + 1} - W_\tau) = E\{E[W_{\tau + 1} - W_\tau | \tau]\} \\
= & \int_0^\infty E[W_{\tau + 1} - W_\tau | \tau = t] f_\tau(t) dt \\
= & \int_0^\infty E[W_{t + 1} - W_t | \tau = t] f_\tau(t) dt \\
= & \int_0^\infty E[W_{t + 1} - W_t] f_\tau(t) dt \quad \text{because } W_{t + 1} - W_t \text{ is independent of } \{\tau = t\} \\
= & 0.
\end{align}

Similarly,
\begin{align}
  & E(W_{\tau + 1} - W_\tau)^2 = E\{E[(W_{\tau + 1} - W_\tau)^2 | \tau]\} \\
= & \int_0^\infty E[(W_{\tau + 1} - W_\tau)^2 | \tau = t] f_\tau(t) dt \\
= & \int_0^\infty E[(W_{t + 1} - W_t)^2 | \tau = t] f_\tau(t) dt \\
= & \int_0^\infty E[(W_{t + 1} - W_t)^2] f_\tau(t) dt \quad \text{because } W_{t + 1} - W_t \text{ is independent of } \{\tau = t\} \\
= & \int_0^\infty f_\tau(t) dt = 1. \quad \text{Use } W_{t + 1} - W_t \sim N(0, 1).
\end{align}

Finally, because $\{W_t\}$ is a martingale, by the optimal sampling theorem, 
$E[W_{\tau \wedge 5}] = EW_5 = 0$.